# Injecting enum using spring dependency injection

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, enums

I am having a `Car` class with different brands like below

```
    public enum Cars{
      FERRARI,
      HONDA,
      SUZUKI;

      private String url;

      public String getUrl() {
        return url;
      }

      public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
      }
  }
```

Also the Car is a dependency in another class. Example is below:

```
public class Showroom{
    private Cars;

    //need to fetch the url
    String url = Cars.FERRARI.url;;
}
```

How to use dependency injection in spring to inject Cars into Showroom and urls into Cars?

Comment: You are envisioning enumerations different then they are actually. They are not replacement for classes. Java allows defining methods and constructors for enumerations, however that does not make them actual classes. Neither `url` nor `Cars` fit in the description of a component. Thus it is not possible to use them as such. If you really need to do it you can achieve it by boxing them into classes, however I fail to see the point.

Comment: Enums are constants. It doesn't make sense to inject them